# How do I create the same mouse over behaviour on an <a> tag on other tags?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

When you mouseover an `<a>` tag in chrome the browser reads the 'href' and displays the link the bottom left corner. Can I mimic this behaviour without using an `<a>` tag?

e.g.
In this situation an `<a>` tag only makes the text clickable on each row and you have to do some hacky css to attempt to get it close to a full row click.

```
<table>
  <tr onClick="goToLink()">
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I notice that gmail doesn't have the  tag hover behaviour when you mouse over an email in the email list view.

My assumption is there is a browser event that I can call to mimic this but I can't seem to find any documentation on this.

Comment: You can’t, but you can put a link inside every cell that spans the entire size of the cell.

Comment: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-a-element

Comment: it must be doable, JS obviously

Comment: If you simply want the `a` link to not be "clickable" or able to be followed, that is another question but would still retain the behavior visually.  This is a browser specific behavior.

Comment: So I want to mimic a tag behaviour in situations where you can't use an a tag. It comes with some handy things such as accessibility and the hover thing described in the questions.

Comment: In earlier times this was possible by setting ```window.status```  via JS but it was disabled by default in all modern browsers. As an alternative you could use the title attribute to display a tool tip or use JS to apply the desired ```a``` tag to every child element automatically.

Comment: You could ditch the `<table>` and use `display: table`, `display: table-row`, and `display: table-cell` where the `<a>` tag is styled as a row. It's still CSS and still uses the `<a>` tag, but it's less hacky.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the effect you want you could just wrap the elements you want clickable in an anchor tag with an href. For example, I've wrapped this blue div in an anchor tag now the entire blue div is clickable and shows the link at the bottom left of the browser:

```css
.clickable-div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">
  <div class="clickable-div"></div>
</a>
```

Comment: This question is for specefically without using an 'a' tag. There are situations such as in the question example where an 'a' tag cannot be wrapped around the element you want to create a link on.

Comment: In that case, no I don't think it's possible. Probably some browser magic provided by the href. If the need is so the user can see the link for the button before clicking it though an alternative approach might be to use a tooltip on hover of the <tr> to display the link url.